# Do I need to put “the” before “most” in this sentence?

Tags: articles, definite-articles, superlative-degree

Is putting “**the**” before “most” in this sentence compulsory, optional, or a mistake?

> Fascination with language and
>   attention to particular regions and
>   communities in America are **the** most common
>   themes for which Coen brothers’ works
>   are appraised.

If it is purely optional, how does its presence or lack change the tone of the sentence, in case it does?

Comment: You do need **the** in this sentence. It is not optional. If you leave it out you still have a grammatical sentence but it doesn't make sense semantically. (I'm too tired to be able to explain it right now though sorry)

Comment: No I retract what I said. Without "the" it can be parsed as the same thing but in a more old-fashioned style as Third Idiot says.

Comment: @hippietrail, I think you really should post it as an answer, and if you don't feel like explaining this right now, perhaps you could make it community wiki.

Comment: @hippietrail: I retract your retraction. Simply dropping the word **the** doesn't leave a valid but old-fashioned utterance. It leaves a bad sentence. It would only be valid (though somewhat archaic) if the sentence ended after the word **themes**.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Now I really can't decide. "Most" used to be used in a sense to mean "very" or "extremely" and I can parse the sentence this way but it's awfully clunky and does not have the usual sense for "most" if you admit it. \-:

Comment: @hippietrail: Yes, I also get ambivalent in exactly the same area. But I find stopping after **themes** just about lets me accept it without **the**, albeit with archaic/stilted/scholarly overtones.

Comment: Your missing the "the" before Coen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Short answer: "The most" is correct here.

Long answer: *Most* can be used as both a [superlative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superlative) and an [intensifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensifier). You are interested in the superlative use: of all the themes under consideration, these are the ones that are present in the greatest number. In formal usage, you would almost always want to use the definite article *the* with a superlative (except for possessive constructions like "John's youngest child").

In practice, *the* is frequently omitted but implied (e.g., "I like this one [the] best"), which complicates the rule somewhat. Nonetheless, if you follow the rule you'll almost always be right.

The other usage of *most* that concerns us here is as a somewhat archaic intensifier, as in Shakespeare's "murder most foul." In this case, *most* is being used as a synonym for *very*, so it doesn't take the definite article. Unless you habitually wear spats and a monocle to dinner, you'll probably want to go easy on this use of *most*.

Comment: Exactly what was in my brain but refused to come out in words (-:

Answer (score 4):

With the "the", you are saying that among all the common themes, these are *the most* common -- the top-ranked ones on the scale of common-ness.  Without the "the", you are saying they're pretty common but there might be others just as common; technically "most" doesn't add anything, but functionally it adds some emphasis.

Comment: No this just isn't right. Without *the* I can only parse *most* in the example as an overly quirky intensifier. If *most* is to be a superlative then *the* is needed in this case if not needed in all cases where *most* is an intensifier.

Answer (score -1):

There is actually no difference. It was common last time to say "most" without "the."
I.e.:

> **Most admirable, Mr. Nestor**

Your example could be rewritten several ways:

> Fascination with language and attention to particular regions and communities in America are  most common themes for which Coen brothers’ works are appraised.

or

> Fascination with language and attention to particular regions and communities in America are *themes most common*, for which Coen brothers’ works are appraised.

Comment: Idiot: Your third example smacks more of Victorian poetry than modern scholarly discourse. The second just sounds stilted.

Comment: I know it smacks of Victorian prose, but that is just what I'm pointing at, it's still correct.

Comment: It's not whether its fashionable or not, its whether its correct

Comment: I think you'd have to go back to Elizabethan times for it to sound like *prose*, but ok

Comment: Read Verne's *Around the World in Eighty Days*