# "most" vs "the most", specifically as an adverb at the end of sentence

Tags: grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

Which one of the following sentences is the most canonical?

I know *most* vs. *the most* has been explained a lot, but my doubts pertain specifically to which one to use **at the end of a sentence**.

> Do you know accepting answers improves your reputation and lets other
>   users know what solution helped you **the most**?

vs

> Do you know accepting answers improves your reputation and lets other
>   users know what solution helped you **most**?

EDIT: [This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197100/the-most-in-english) doesn't solve my doubts because it is not about using "most" and "the most" specifically as an adverb at the end of a sentence.

Comment: possible duplicate of [\*the most\* in english](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/197100/the-most-in-english)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Most**

We use the quantifier most to talk about quantities, amounts and degree. We can use it with a noun (as a determiner) or without a noun (as a pronoun). We can also use it with adjectives and adverbs to form the superlative.

> **The most** is the superlative form of **many, much**.

We use the most to make the superlative forms of longer adjectives and the majority of adverbs:

- They’re using the most advanced technology in the world. (+
  adjective)
- Scafell Pike is the most easily identifiable peak in the Lake
  District. (+ adverb)

> **The most** **with a noun.**

***We use the most with a noun to mean ‘more/less than all of the others’:***

- Ian earns the most money in our family.

> **The most with a verb**.

We use the most with a verb as an adverb:

- **They all cried, but Claire cried the most.**

**(**[Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly)**)**

> Do you know accepting answers improves your reputation and let other
>   users know what solution helped (you) **the most**?

Comment: So in the examples I gave the correct use is the second one since it's used as an adverb to the verb help. Am I right?

Comment: In the link to [the] least from your link, one finds: << We use _least_ and _the least_ with a verb as an adverb:

_None of them worked much, but Karen worked the least._ >> It's surprising that CDO don't also give the alternative _most_ alongside _the most_. As Marius's results show, it's not uncommon. I'm quite familiar with it. 'I like soccer most' is quite acceptable and appears on the internet. 'I like soccer most of all' is quite common.

Answer (score 2):

Search at Google Books, adding an **"and" that is very similar to a sentence end** in its effect (i.e., you can consider "and" as starting a new sentence):

["helped you most **and**"](https://www.google.ca/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=%22what%20helped%20you%20the%20most%20and%22#hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22helped%20you%20most%20and%22)
About 430 results

["helped you the most **and**"](https://www.google.ca/search?hl=en&tbm=bks&q=%22helped%20you%20the%20most%20and%22&ei=1JcmVYKoJtPgsASxlIGQCQ)
About 104 results

Both are pretty well represented, thus considered correct by various authors and their editors. Based on frequency, one should select the first, but **I prefer the 2nd as it avoids the feeling of clipping**.

Comment: The question is not really suitable for ELU, but your search filter device is very clever.