# I like the dog most vs I like the dog the most

Tags: grammar

Is there any difference between those two sentences?

I like the dog most - "most" is adverb.
I like the dog the most - "the most" can be adverb?

Which one is right ? Or two sentences are right?

Comment: What two sentences?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["most" vs "the most", specifically as an adverb at the end of sentence](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/238372/most-vs-the-most-specifically-as-an-adverb-at-the-end-of-sentence) Also [Which is more common - 'the most' or 'most'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73812/which-is-more-common-the-most-or-most) and several others.