# When to use "most" or "the most"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, word-usage, adverbs, sentence

I came across with this sentence and it cast me doubt the usage of "most" and "the most"

The sentence states: "But what I remembered **most** is moving a lot"

Would it change the meaning of the sentence if I interchange "most" with "the most"? I am a little confused about when to use these words.

Previous to this post I searched for the difference between these words but I think I need not only the definition but examples to distinguish their usage. Thank you

Comment: Have you checked to see if a similar question has already been answered?

Comment: I don't think there's much difference from adding _the_.

Comment: Consider *"What it was that I remembered the most is [moving a lot]"*, er, and *"I remembered [moving a lot] the most"*. The function of "moving a lot" in that last example seems to be that of object; consider where it is replaced by a NP "my first girlfriend": *"I remembered [my first girlfriend] the most"*, where it seems unquestionable an object. Now if it is cleaved into two to form a cleft, we could get something like: *"But what I remembered the most is/was [my first girlfriend]"*. Interestingly, dropping the "the" in "the most" in the last example and in OP's example seems okay to me.

Comment: @F.E. Dropping _the_ seems perfectly fine to me in **all** the examples you gave.

Comment: Related (though not a duplicate): [_Which is more common - 'the most' or 'most'?_](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73812/which-is-more-common-the-most-or-most)

Comment: There's some related info in H&P's *CGEL*, such as on pages 1168-9 [23], where it discusses factors influencing the presence or absence of the word "the" w.r.t. superlatives.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"But what I remembered *most* is moving a lot" is correct, with or without "the". Although "the most" is the *superlative*, preferable.

Here, "most" is used as an **adverb** modifying the verb "remember", meaning "to the greatest extent". There may be other examples, where it can mean "extremely" as in the following:"it was most kind of you", "that is most probably correct".

As an *adjective* while qualifying a *noun*, it takes "the" as in the following example:
Here's the most expensive book I ever bought.

As a noun, "most" takes the definite article. For example, "The most (that) you can do is to try again."

For further review: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/most http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/most-the-most-mostly

Comment: This is **utterly incorrect**. Using _the most_ in the example in the question here is perfectly grammatical and exceedingly common. There is nothing ungrammatical or incorrect about it. The adverbial use of the definite noun _the most_ synonymous with the bare-adverbial _most_ to modify an entire clause or predicate has been in use since at least the 1500s and is an integral part of English.

Comment: Also, in your positive/comparative/superlative examples, _much/more/most_ will most commonly be perceived as (pro)nouns acting as direct objects, rather than adverbs modifying the noun. You’d have to add an actual direct object to force the adverbial meaning (and then you’d realise that the _much_ sentence would become ungrammatical), or you’d have to move the adverb before the verb.

Comment: Could we therefore say that "the" is also common in the superlatives as an adj or adv? Oxford doesn't give examples with "the". Could you give an example here as an adverb, with the rules governing the use of "the", for the sake of clarifying this both to the poster and me?

Answer (score 0):

'Most' is the superlative form of "much and many" and used as adjective, adverb and noun.

As noun:

```
The most I can offer for the house is $100,000.
```

(Don't put forth the argument adjective & article combination to be noun.)

The superlative with "most" is sometimes used when there is no ideas of comparison, but merely a desire to indicate a quality in a very high degree. (Grammar Ref.)

```
This is most convenient.
This is a most wonderful sight.
It was a most eloquent speech.
```

It should be noted that even though 'most' is in superlative form, 'the' is not used before it. Sometimes, 'most' goes without article or sometimes it takes 'a' instead of 'the'.

In your example it is an adverb; and without 'the' amply conveys what is meant.----there is no idea of comparison.

Comment: There is absolutely a notion of comparison in the sentence given in the question. It means ‘most of all’, which is inherently comparative in nature. Comparison is only foregone when _most_ is used adverbially to modify adjectives, synonymous to _very_, which is not the case here.

Comment: It is from personal perspective, Janus. To me it seems'what is uppermost in his mind'.

Comment: Exactly. And _uppermost_ implies a comparison.

Comment: @Barid Baran Acharya: To me, using "a" in a superlative form doesn't seem correct. The following would be:
This is "the" most convenient.
This is "the" most wonderful sight.
It was "the" most eloquent speech.

Comment: What would you say to Oscar Wilde's  Selfish Giant when he rubbed the sleep from his eyes.--What did he see?                                                              --He saw  a most wonderful sight.                          And  was amazed like both of us.

Comment: Yes, but he wasn't fully awake like us.

Comment: But I fully agree with you that superlative adjectives take 'the' before them, superlative adverbs do not even if a sense of comparison is introduced by application of 'of or in'. : P T Usha runs fastest (most quickly) of all Indian women.

Comment: You're right. However, in your example, "... runs the fastest..." would also be correct.

Answer (score -1):

I believe when we use the 'the' its more based on perspective than fact.  This also depends on where you place your words in a sentence and which words they are as well.  The 'the' article places importance on the object that the speaker or writer is speaking or writing about. 'A' does not do this, it just states that out of many ... there was a... (you can fill in the blanks as you see fit).

This sentence would be incorrect: "the most countries I've been to, are 10". We would need to add something to this sentence so it would look like this: "the most number of countries I've been to..." However, we can use, "the most frustrating thing about... is..."