# Absolute superlative

Tags: grammar, adjectives, sentence, articles, superlative-degree

"2020 is said to be a darkest year"

I learned in my book that the superlative with most is sometimes used when there's no idea of comparison but to show the existence of a quality of a very high degree. I read in one of the posts here that *the* is omitted before it is used in this way and the article *a* is place instead.

Is sentence my correct?

Forgive me if I made any grammatical mistakes.

Comment: Your text *"2020 is said to be a darkest year"* isn't something a native speaker would ever be likely to say. I think what you read about is the usage whereby we say things like *John is **a most** charming fellow, You are **most** kind!, This is **most** inconvenient.* Where ***most*** doesn't exactly mean *of the **highest** degree* - it's really just a rather dated/formal alternative to ***very***. But note that although we *can* use the indefinite article in my first example,  we don't *have* to. There's nothing wrong with *John is **the most** charming fellow!*

Comment: Related: [When to use “most” or “the most”,](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257401/) and [Superlatives with “the”.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30272/)

Comment: It should ***the*** *darkest year*, ***one of the*** *darkest years*, *a **dark** year*, or *a **darker** year*. You can refer to a collective of things as being darker than anything else outside the collective, but you can't have multiple individual things that are each darker than the others. (A can't be darker than B at the same time that B is darker than A.)