# Why do we use "the most" as in "Which countries travel the most?", why not just "Which countries travel most?"

Tags: word-choice

Recently, I discovered that some people use `the most` in sentences such as `Which countries travel the most` or `we stress the last number the most`.

Why not just `most`?

For example, is it ok to say `Which countries travel most` or `we stress the last number most`.

`the most` sounds very strange to my ears.

Extra info: So what is the difference between:

**Which one do you love most?**

and

**Which one do you love the most?**

Comment: Countries don't travel—people travel.

Answer (score -1):

The correct question is the first one though, cuz in case you want to say, what countries travel most? Then you should use more instead of most. Hence, every time you use **most** you must add **the**. 
`The most beautiful thing.`
She is most beautiful girl on Earth.`this one sounds weird cuz I didn't put "the"`

Comment: So what is the difference between:

Which one do you love most?

and 

Which one do you love the most?

Comment: No difference, "the" is often left out in informal English. If you google on both expressions, "most" is more commonly used. Refer to [this discussion](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/73812/which-is-more-common-the-most-or-most).